# HighCharts multiple axis not recognized

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have this JSON, but I'm getting this error:

[The requested axis does not exist](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/18/)

```
yAxis: [
    { title: { text: 'Some text 1' }, },
    { title: { text: 'Some text 2' }, },
],
series: [
    { name: 'Some name 1', data: someData, yAxis: 1, }
    { name: 'Some name 2', data: someData, yAxis: 2, }
]
```

How do I associate each series with its respective yAxis?

Answer (score 0):

Wow... the axes are zero-indexed...

But if you look at the API documentation on their website, it's not.

[Multiple axes](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)

Comment: On the shared demo, the axes are zero-indexed too, notice that demo includes three y-axes. The `temperature` series is attached to the zero indexed yAxis by default.